# Как с помощью js удалить дубликаты элементов списка ul

Tags: javascript

под дубликатами имеется ввиду не одинаковые классы, а именно содержимое элементов li.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function removeDuplicates(ulEl) {
    const map = {};
    for (let i = 0; i < ulEl.children.length; i++) {
        const child = ulEl.children[i];
        if (child.innerHTML in map) child.remove();
        else map[child.innerHTML] = true;
    }
}

removeDuplicates(document.querySelector('ul'));
```